# Cmake and gtest in VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, googletest

I'm having trouble running gtest with cmake in VS2019. It seems like VS test explorer couldn't find my tests. I'm following this [instructions](https://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-cmake.html)

My `CmakeLists.txt` (testing part, after project config):

```
enable_testing()
find_package(GTest CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(GatewayTests
  testsG/GatewayMTests.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(GatewayTests
  PRIVATE GTest::gmock GTest::gtest GTest::gmock_main GTest::gtest_main
)
include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(GatewayTests)
```

My `GatewayMTests.cpp`:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <format>

    TEST(HelloTest, BasicAssertions) {
        // Expect two strings not to be equal.
        EXPECT_STRNE("hello", "world");
        // Expect equality.
        EXPECT_EQ(7 * 6, 43);
    }
```

Everything builds fine, but VS test explorer can't find any tests. Is there anything I've missed?

UPD:
I also ran this version of `CMakelists.txt`:

```
enable_testing()
find_package            (GTest CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_executable          (GatewayTests testsG/GatewayMTests.cpp)
target_link_libraries   (GatewayTests PRIVATE GTest::gmock GTest::gtest GTest::gmock_main GTest::gtest_main)
add_test                (GatewayTests GatewayTests )
```

Now test explorer sees this test:
[image]

And somehow it passed. I've tried run tests in debug, but it never gets past signature:
[image]

Comment: Have you enabled the feature [Test Adapter for Google Test](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualCPPTeam.TestAdapterforGoogleTest) in Visual Studio Installer?

Comment: Yes, I did. I've actually used test explorer in VS sln projects, it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out problem was within build location. My `CMakelists.txt` for main project contained next option:

```
set(OUTPUT_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/${PLATFORM_ARCHITECTURE}/$<CONFIG>)
set(PROJ_CONFIG $<CONFIG>)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_DIR}/
)
```

And tests were building in different directory. I've just added

```
set_target_properties(GatewayTests 
    PROPERTIES
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_DIR}/
)
```

and problem has solved.