# CMake and GTest in VS 2019 test building failure

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019, googletest

Somehow I have the same problem I had last time [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70890534/cmake-and-gtest-in-vs2019) and I can't solve it this time.
I have my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.20)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/Users/JackOfShadows/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")

project ("CMakeProject1")

find_package(GTest CONFIG REQUIRED)
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

add_executable (CMakeProject1 "main.cpp" TestClass.cpp TestClass.h)
target_link_libraries (CMakeProject1
    PRIVATE GTest::gmock GTest::gtest GTest::gmock_main GTest::gtest_main
)

enable_testing()
find_package(GTest CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_executable(SomeTests
    "AppTests.cpp" TestClass.cpp TestClass.h
)

target_link_libraries (SomeTests
    PRIVATE GTest::gmock GTest::gtest GTest::gmock_main GTest::gtest_main
)

include (GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(SomeTests)
```

It builds and links as it's supposed to. But no tests are discovered in `AppTests.cpp`:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

namespace SomeNamespaceTests {
    // Demonstrate some basic assertions.

    TEST(HelloTest, BasicAssertions) {

        // Expect two strings not to be equal.
        EXPECT_STRNE("hello", "world");
        // Expect equality.
        EXPECT_EQ(7 * 6, 42);
    }
}
```

[image: TestResult]

Comment: BTW, you don't need to quote the first cpp file in your `add_executable()`. You only need to use quotes if there is a space in the filename or path.

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah, thanks, It automatically generated by VS2019. I've actually removed them at this point. Do you have any clues regarding my problem?

Comment: This does not look like a building failure. Instead the failure is its not detecting or running your tests. I can't help with gtest I have used CTest from the start (2008) with Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the reason, but you don't have to link against all four gtest libraries. Right now you're linking against gmock_main and gtest_main. Both dependencies implement `main`. Your output suggests your executable is invoking gmock_main. Simply linking against gmock_main should be sufficient.

Comment: @local-ninja Thanks a lot, that did it. I noticed that in my previous project I only linked to gtest_main, but couldn't think that is the reason for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per suggerstion by @local_ninja I've linked project only to gtest_main and now tests are running okay.